# SSRS: How to print a report without bringing up the rendered report?

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I'm wondering how to print a SSRS report without bringing up a report viewer. Right now my users have to press the Print button, bring up the rendered report, and then press Print again.

Current Code:

```
Dim report as new ReportViewer
'snip - fill datasets, set data sources, blah blah blah
report.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
report.Show()
```

This brings up a viewer window, which I don't really want, since my users then have to press Print again.

So I added the following:

```
report.PrintDialog()
```

The above code results in an `invalidOperationException` because it hasn't finished rendering. I understand that, but is there a way to render the report programmatically (rather than onscreen) and send the user straight to the printer dialogue?

EDIT: OK, I'm 90% there. `PrintDialog()` isn't the way to go. I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/MicrosoftReportsII.aspx) but it results in an `InvalidXMLException`. It doesn't tell me why it's wrong, just that it's wrong... The API is totally unhelpful so... help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SSRS Web Service to programmatically render the report (i.e. as a PDF) and then print it from your application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152952.aspx

Comment: I've tried calling `render([args])` and then `printDialog()` and it still throws the same error. Would you be able to provide a code example?

Comment: I've used this code sample in the past (for SQL 2005) to render to PDF programmatically: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/PDFUsingSQLRepServices.aspx

Using this method you should then print the PDF externally, not use the printDialog() method.

Comment: I'm so close, but this InvalidXMLException is my only roadblock.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I found on the subject, followed, and worked for me:
http://printssrsreport.blogspot.com/2011/09/print-ssrs-report-using.html

It's important you follow "Step 1" and add the reference to "ReportExecution2005.asmx".  This was confusing to me as I am using Reporting Services 2008 R2.  But it is what it is, and it works.

The rest should be straight forward and work for you.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the reports on a schedule, get them to save as a pdf to a folder then use something like [Batch print pro](http://www.traction-software.co.uk/batchprint/index.html) to print them?

Comment: It's just the XML error I'm running into at this stage, and I'm pretty sure (famous last words) that if I overcame that, my current code would do :)

Answer (score 0):

try to put the command `report.PrintDialog()` on the `RenderingComplete` event of the `ReportViewer` Control.

this will insure that the report is already rendered before you call the print dialog